# Android:How to save perennialy a variable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a variable and I want to change it only the first time that I start my app. For example:

1. I open the app: Variable is not initialized. Variable changes to 4.
2. I close the app
3. I open the app Variable is 4.

And so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are new to Android. You can save the values using "SharedPreferences".

Check this link : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Also check out this example :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

You can use this code :

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

Here, MyPREFERENCES is the file name. Replace the "value" with the variable name.
Again, if you want to retrieve the value, then use:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.getBoolean("key", true);
//There are other methods like getInt(),getDouoble().getString() depending on the type of value
```

Comment: I have modifies the link. You can check now! I have also added the sample code.

Comment: Is MyPreferences a file.txt ?

Comment: yes, it is where your keys and values are stored. You can provide any name

Comment: I didn't find Editor but SharedPreferences.Editor. Is it the same?

Comment: Yes, Editor is a subclass of SharedPreferences.

Comment: but for example, if I write prefs.getInt("key", 12), it returns 12. But what is the method editor.putInt("key", "7) used for?

Comment: getInt("key","default_value") is the actual method. If the key is found, the corresponding value is returned .If not, the default value is returned. The method putInt("key","value") is used to store the value. SO as per your example, getInt("key",12) returns the value if the key is matched. Otherwise, 12 is returned.

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) doesn't work, but         SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 works

Answer (score 0):

You can also write to a local file and use SQLite for that purposes if you would like to persist big object's data.